# Sending photos to Telegram using the SendMediaGroupAsync method c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telegram, telegram-bot

I need to send a photo album in a bundle to the telegram bot. The number of photos is unknown in advance.
I wrote the code:

```
List<IAlbumInputMedia> streamArray = new List<IAlbumInputMedia> {};
 foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    using var stream = formFile.OpenReadStream();
                    streamArray.Add(stream); // there is a mistake here. cannot convert to System.IO.Stream to Telegram.Bot.Types.IAlbumInputmedia
                    //await clientTg.SendPhotoAsync(groupId,stream); // it works fine
                }
            }
 
            await clientTg.SendMediaGroupAsync(groupId, streamArray);
```

I can't add **stream** to List arrayStream, error "**cannot convert to System.IO.Stream to Telegram.Bot.Types.IAlbumInputmedia**"
In a single instance, the stream is normally sent via the SendPhotoAsync method, commented out in the code.
How do I convert these types and send a group photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/send-msg/album-msg.html):

```
Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
    chatId: chatId,
    media: new IAlbumInputMedia[]
    {
        new InputMediaPhoto("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/20/19/22/fuchs-2424369_640.jpg"),
        new InputMediaPhoto("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/04/11/21/34/giraffe-2222908_640.jpg"),
    }
);
```

You must explicitly set the type of files.

In your case it will be like:

```
streamArray.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(stream, $"file{DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", ".")}")
```

Comment: it also didn't work. Apparently you can't use Add in this case.
But your code pushed me in the right direction. I decided to write code for a different number of photos of different branches of the program. Thanks!

Comment: @RCdag05 I think, it is because the streams are already closed, when you call clientTg.SendMediaGroupAsync (and code execution of getting data happens here). You can release the streams on your own: remove 'using' keyword here, add foreach that will close each stream in the end (after SendMediaGroupAsync method).

Comment: you are using the 'using' keyword inside the 'if' scope, it means when you exit this block, the method Dispose will be called, that will clean-up kept resources of that stream.  It means the object is destroyed and you can't access it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[@Vadim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973907/3025856) didn't work, probably because I can't `Add` in this case. But their answer did push me in the right direction. I decided to write code for a different number of photos of different branches of the program.

```
if (files.Count == 2) // <<<< 2 photos
{
    await using var stream1 = files[0].OpenReadStream();
    await using var stream2 = files[1].OpenReadStream();
    IAlbumInputMedia[] streamArray =
    {
        new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(stream1, "111"))
        {
            Caption = "Cap 111"
        },
        new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(stream2, "222"))
        {
            Caption = "Cap 222"
        },
    };
    await clientTg.SendMediaGroupAsync(groupId, streamArray);
}
```

I'm not sure that I'm using `await using` correctly, but at least it works.